# Php/Zend/SSH - Unable to receive remote file

Tags: php, ssh, zend-framework

Im trying to connect with my ssh server and download a file but i got a problem and i don't understand why. The file exist for sure, i search on internet but i didn't find anything to unbug this.

Error:

> COPY ERROR: 2
>      ssh2_scp_recv() [function.ssh2-scp-recv]: Unable to receive remote file

My code:

```
public function ajaxdownloadfileAction() {

        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

        $this->view->lib = $this->_labelsFile;

        $connection = ssh2_connect($this->_configFile->ftp->hostname, $this->_configFile->ftp->port);
        if ($connection) {
            $login = ssh2_auth_password($connection, $this->_configFile->ftp->login, $this->_configFile->ftp->password);
            if ($login) {
                $content = true;
                if ($content) { 
                    $local = ' C:\Users\Public\Downloads ';
                    $fileName = "\\Talend\\PEC_DF6\\FluxSortantAdmissionPEC\\ARCHIVES\\XML\\wzadyyyy.0001054581.ap.xml";   
                    if(!@ssh2_scp_recv($connection,$fileName,$local)){
                        $errors= error_get_last();
                        echo "COPY ERROR: ".$errors['type'];
                        echo "<br />\n".$errors['message'];
                    }
                    else {
                            echo "File copied from remote!";
                        }
                    //$filename = $this->getRequest()->getParam('name'); 
                   // $fileName = "\\Talend\\PEC_DF6\\FluxSortantAdmissionPEC\\ARCHIVES\\XML\\wzadyyyy.0001054581.ap.xml";  
                    //$fileName = $this->_getParam('fileName');  
                    //echo $fileName;die;

                    //ssh2_scp_recv($connection,$filename,$local);

            }
            $connection = null; unset($connection);
        }
     }

    /* $result['status'] = 'OK';
     $result['message'] = 'LE ficheir a bien ete telecharger';

     echo json_encode($result);*/
}
```

Comment: Does the local target exist, with spaces in the front and in the end?

Comment: I tried without space but it still not working, i think the problem come from : there is a default path when im connecting to the ssh. It may be that ? @NicoHaase

Comment: Are you sure that you are not mixing things up? You build up the connection using  `$this->_configFile->ftp` (which indicates the usage of FTP), then you open a connection using `ssh2_scp_recv` (which indicates the usage of SCP), then you request the source files using a path using backslashes, while a Unix system uses forward slashes

Comment: The $this->_configfile->ftp wouldnt change anything because it's from a .ini file. The connection is working, the probleme is the ssh2_scp_recv(). I tried to switch blackshlash as you tell me but it change nothing :( @NicoHaase

Comment: Have you tried logging into that source system manually and check for the proper path? Is it a Windows system or a Unix based?

Comment: I will try to connect with cli, my client is windows based but the ssh server is Unix based

Comment: ok i tried with command line interface and i found something, the files are not with exectution permissed in the ssh server, it's probably a cause of this @NicoHaase